# Binary to decimal with fold

Tags: haskell, fold

Hey guys we got the question: that we should write a function bin2dez
with the condition: gets a natural number and returns the decimal representation
of the number as a string. Use a fold for this.

```
bin2dez :: (Int -> [Int] -> [Int]) -> [Int] -> Int -> [Int] 
bin2dez xs = foldr f 0 
  where
  f = bin1dez (drehe xs) 
  bin1dez :: [Int] -> Int
  bin1dez [] = 0
  bin1dez (x:xs) = 2*(bin1dez xs) + x
  drehe [] = []
  drehe (x:xs) = drehe xs ++ [x]
```

I'm confused about the fold here, because you need a function f and a neutral element, the neutral element should be 0 here, but how can I enter this in Haskell, could someone help me, thanks

```
bin2dez :: [Int] -> Int
bin2dez xs = foldr f b
where b = 0
      f result x = bin1dez (drehe xs) 
  bin1dez [] = 0
  bin1dez = 2*(bin1dez xs) + x
  drehe [] = []
  drehe (x:xs) = drehe xs ++ [x]
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean a [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution), and not a [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function))? (These are completely different words in English, though they translate to the same word in some other languages, like “Faltung” in German.)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I mean fold

Comment: Ok. And, why do you have that complicated higher-order function signature, if this is just supposed to calculate the decimal expansion of an integer? That should simply be `Int -> [Int]`, no?

Answer (score 0):

When you're asked to "use a fold", the idea is to use the fold to replace what would otherwise be written as a recursion over the input structure.  For example, if you have a recursion to sum a list of numbers:

```
mysum (x:xs) = x + mysum xs
mysum [] = 0
```

and you're asked to "use a fold", you're supposed to isolate the base case for the empty list (result `0`) and the calculation used to combine the head of the list with the recursively calculated result for its tail:

```
f head_of_list result_for_tail = head_of_list + result_for_tail
```

and write it as a non-recursive function using a fold:

```
mysum xs = foldr f b xs
  where b = 0          -- base case
        f h t = h + t  -- combine head with result for tail
```

or more simply:

```
mysum = foldr (+) 0
```

You already have a recursive binary-to-decimal conversion function:

```
bin1dez :: [Int] -> Int
bin1dez [] = 0
bin1dez (x:xs) = 2*(bin1dez xs) + x
```

e.g.,

```
> bin1dez [1,1,0,1]   -- least significant bit first
11
```

To "use a fold", you want to identify the base case (easy) and isolate the function that combines the head `x` and the recursively calculated tail result `bin1dez xs`.  That is, you need to derive a (non-recursive) function:

```
f x result_for_xs = ...expression using x and result_for_xs...
```

from your recursive definition.  Using the base case and that function, you'll be able to define your fold.

If your binary representation is "most significant bit first" (and it looks like it is, given your `drehe` function), you may want to consider the *left* fold function `foldl`.  This takes a base case for the empty "start" of a list and a function that combines the result for the initial part of the list (first argument) with the next element in the list (second argument) to produce a result for an initial segment of the list.

In other words, if you have a right fold solution for the least significant bit first:

```
bin2dez = foldr f b
  where b = ...
        f x result = ...

> bin2dez [1,1,0,1]
11
```

you can convert it to a left fold solution for the most significant bit first without having to reverse the list:

```
bin2dez = foldl f b
  where b = ...same as above...
        f result x = ...same function body...
          ^^^^^^^^- swap these arguments

> bin2dez [1,1,0,1]
13
```

The extra part of this problem "returns the decimal representation of the number **as a string**" is weird.  You wouldn't normally do this with a fold.  (It's actually an "unfolding".)  If you're not allowed to just call `show` on the result of the fold, I'm not sure what your instructor actually intends for you to do here.

Comment: Okay, at first thank you very much, maybe I´m to stupid, but it also didnt work. My try was that:                                                                                                                             
`bin2dez :: [Int] -> Int
bin2dez xs = foldr f b
    where b = 0
          f result x = bin1dez (drehe xs) 
 bin1dez [] = 0
 bin1dez = 2*(bin1dez xs) + x
 drehe [] = []
 drehe (x:xs) = drehe xs ++ [x]`

Comment: You're still trying to use recursion in `f` by calling the recursive functions `bin1dez` and `drehe`.  You should be able to write `f` as a one-line calculation that calls no other functions, besides the operators `*` and `+`.  For the `mysum` example, `f` was just `f x result = x + result`.  Your `f` should be almost as simple.